# Why are my table view delegate methods not being called on -reloadData?

Tags: iphone

i have NSobject page inwhich i have method to reload table
like

```
MainPageTable *m = [[ MainPageTable alloc] init];
[m.tableView reloadData];
[m release];
```

The following is called:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

but this is not:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

mm. reloadData is a standart tableView's method. after this call your tablewView asks it's delegate and dataSource about info it's need to be reloaded as numbers of sections in the table after reload, new cells, etc.

Comment: yes,section returns 10, i checked through break point, but when i put
break point on cellForRowAtIndexPath ,it will not be worked....
any help please?

Comment: new cells will not be displayed after reloading

Comment: hmm. maybe you put breakpoint in some, for exaple, if block? or it is in the beginning of cellForRowAtIndexPath? is this method called when you load your table at the first time?

Comment: YES..it works first time. after i changed its section to 10 from NSObject ,then the break point goes to numberOfRowsInSection correctly(changed) then the break point( already worked ) is not worked, it did not get new cells(already worked) will you please help?

Comment: ok. first of all - why do you create new object to relod data? if you already have your page, you may not crate it to call reloadData. if you just created your page, your table will ask it's delegate and dataSource methods automatically. second. if you have created your table in IB, then it can just has no enough time to load and you send reloadData to nil object. check it in debugger and post results.

Comment: bcos i have xmlparser page(nsobject page) in which , after finishing
xml parsing i need to create object for that tableview,and then i call reload data.how can i post debugger result?what it means? will you please?

Comment: i have tableview in IB...what i have to do?

Comment: how can i avoid reloadData to nil object?